# Expected value and probability mass above zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Z$ be a random variable with with pdf $f(z)$. I am wondering whether the expected value $E(Z)$ is proportional to the density mass of $f(z)$ that is in the positive range. This is something that I assume may hold due to graphical intuition. If this is true, how can we show it?

I think it may be useful to start with the definitions of the mass of $f(z)$ above zero

$\int_0^\infty f(z) ~dz$

and the expected value

$E(Z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty z f(z) ~dz = \int_{-\infty}^0 z f(z) ~dz +
 \int_0^\infty z f(z) ~dz$

but I'm not sure how to go on from here.

Edit: My goal would be something like $E(Z) \propto \int_0^\infty f(z) ~dz$.

Comment: Keep in mind the PDF doesn't have to be symmetric around zero in general

Comment: Still, for something skewed such as a Pareto distribution, an increasing probability mass above zero implies an increasing expected value and vice versa, or do I miss something?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “proportional to $f(z)$ in the positive range”? Can you write a math equation for your conjecture? When you say “I’m not sure how to go on”, what is your end goal?

Comment: Added where I want to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only are the two quantities not literally proportional, but they are not even approximately proportional.

**Claim**: for *any* real numbers $E$ and $p$ with $0<p<1$, there exists a random variable $X$ such that $\Bbb E(X)=E$ and $\mathop{\rm Pr}(X>0) = p$.

**Construction** for a discrete random variable: let $a>\max\{0,\frac Ep\}$ be any real number. Let $X$ take the value $a$ with probability $p$, and take the value $-\frac{pa-E}{1-p}$ with probability $1-p$. Note that $a$ is positive by assumption, while $b$ is negative by the lower bound on $a$. Therefore $\mathop{\rm Pr}(X>0) = p$, and
$$
\Bbb E(X)= p\cdot a + (1-p) \cdot \bigg({-}\frac{pa-E}{1-p}\bigg) = pa-(pa-E) = E.
$$

If one wants a continuous random variable, one can approximate this discrete random variable as closely as desired.